# How can I list the objects (views, mostly) I updated in the last 2 weeks in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I ran this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.all_views 
where view_name like 'V%DIMFE%'
```

but I would like to have the 'last changed' date. is that possible ? (I don't have DBA permissions, but I guess I could ask a colleague to run it for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select last_ddl_time
from all_objects
where object_type = 'VIEW'
```

should give the hint

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Oguen answer, I ended up with this:

```
select owner, object_type, object_name, last_ddl_time, created
from all_objects
where object_type IN  ('VIEW', 'TABLE')
--and owner = 'XYZ'
and object_name like '%ABC%'
and last_ddl_time >= trunc(sysdate - 15)  --last 15 days
order by object_type, object_name;
```